# Samtools Index: Chromosome Blocks not Continuous

Tags: genome, samtools, bwa, indexing

I am working with short-read whole-genome sequences from the NCBI's SRA. I have aligned and sorted all of my short-read sequences and am attempting to index each sequence into .bai format using samtools index, but am running into a couple of errors.

I unpacked the original .sra files in the following manner:

```
fastq-dump --defline-seq '@$sn[_$rn]/$ri' --split-files SRR6509138.sra
```

I then aligned each fastq paired-end read, removed duplicate reads, and converted each to bam format like so:

```
bwa mem xiphophorus_birchmanni_10x_12Sep2018_yDAA6.fasta SRR6509136_1.fastq SRR6509136_2.fastq | samblaster -e -r| samtools view -Sb - > blasted_SRR6509136.bam
```

Some of my files did not come as paired-end reads. For those files, I used the --ignoreUnmated flag on samblaster.

I then sorted each bam file like so:

```
samtools sort blasted_SRR6649368.bam -o sorted_SRR6649368.bam -n
```

I am attempting to obtain a bai file for each bam using the following command:

```
samtools index sorted_SRR6649368.bam sorted_SRR6649368.bam.bai
```

This is the error I run into for the unpaired reads:

```
[E::hts_idx_push] Chromosome blocks not continuous
[E::sam_index] Read 'HWI-ST387:164:D0CJWACXX:4:1101:1129:13264' with ref_name='ScdB1pO_646;HRSCAF=880', ref_length=33092979, flags=16, pos=23260108 cannot be indexed
samtools index: failed to create index for "sorted_SRR791885.bam": No such file or directory
```

This is the error I run into for the paired reads:

```
[E::hts_idx_push] Unsorted positions on sequence #79: 11159020 followed by 11158717
samtools index: failed to create index for "sorted_SRR6649368.bam"
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Are there some instructions you are following that tell you to use these commands? Where has the idea that you need to use `-n` on the `samtools sort` command here come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
samtools sort blasted_SRR6649368.bam -o sorted_SRR6649368.bam -n
```

These error messages indicate that the reads are not sorted by coordinate — in particular, that the reads mapped to *ScdB1pO_646;HRSCAF=880* are not all together, and that the reads at positions 11159020 < 11158717 are not sorted by position on their chromosome.

This is because `samtools sort -n` has been used to sort the reads by name instead. Remove `-n` to sort by position, which is what is needed to prepare a BAM file for indexing with `samtools index`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! As for why I used the -n flag, I am trying replicate the results of a journal article. The journal article did not provide explicit instructions for sorting/indexing the files, and this is my first time sorting/indexing files. I think "sort by reads" simply _sounded_ like the correct thing to do, but it looks like I was incorrect